# Reduce the size of a camera captured picture in c#

Tags: windows-mobile

I want to know how to reduce the size of a camera captured picture in windows mobile.  I would also like to know how I can save it to a database and show it in picture box.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Tacke had a great post about that:

http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2010/10/13/LoadingPartsOfLargeImagesInTheCompactFramework.aspx

It included zooming into the picture, but if you don't want that you could just leave that part of the implementation out.